# how can i get token from firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to get fcm token from getToken in firebase

but if i use my code token comes out like this

[image]

How can i get ?

this is my code

```
    const App = ({}) => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();

      useEffect(() => {
        const fcmtoken = messaging()
          .getToken()
          .then((mainToken) => {
            return mainToken;
          });

        console.log('fcmtoken:::', fcmtoken);
      }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getToken()` call is asynchronous, and so it returns a promise. That's the structure your `console.log` actually outputs.

To get the actual value from a promise, you have to hook its `then()` callback, same as you already do for `getToken()`.

So, this would work:

```
const fcmtoken = messaging()
  .getToken()
  .then((mainToken) => {
    return mainToken;
  });

fcmtoken.then((token) => console.log('fcmtoken:::', token));
```

Typically you'll want to dispatch the token when you've gotten it, meaning you'll call `dispatch` inside the callback, where you now do `return mainToken`. Just dispatch the token there, and don't return anything.